# HTML-Popup and Gallery simultaneously on Highslide

Tags: highslide

I'm new on using Highslide and I have a question.
How can I open a Gallery and a HTML-Popup on the same page ?

Answer (score 0):

This page coding of this example should get you on the right track:

http://www.roadrash.no/hs-support/gallery-horizontal-strip+html.html

The key to it is to define a slideshow group for the gallery, and tag all the gallery images as being part of that group, while *not* tagging the HTML popup that way.